# Lighting issue in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, lighting

I have trouble developing an OpenGL application.

The weird thing is that me and a friend of mine are developing a 3d scene with OpenGL under Linux, and there is some code on the repository, but if we both checkout the same latest version, that means, the SAME code this happens: On his computer after he compiles he can see the full lighting model, whilst on mine, I have only the ambient lights activated but not the diffuse or specular ones.

Can it be a problem of drivers ?(since he uses an ATi card and I use an nVIDIA one)
Or the static libraries ?

I repeat, it is the same code, compiled in different machines.. that's the strange thing, it should look the same.

Thanks for any help or tip given.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can very easily be a driver problem, or one card supporting extensions that the other does not.

Try his binaries on your machine. If it continues to fail, either your drivers are whack or you're using a command not supported by your card. On the other hand if your screen looks right when using your code compiled on his machine, then your static libraries have a problem.

Comment: Yes, you're right, it is a drivers issue. I have tried the binaries on my machine, and compiled the program in different machines. With the newer nVIDIA cards and Ubuntu it happens the same in all the PCs I tested.